# Change the paragraph type to list item type using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to change the paragraph to list type of those that begin with ##.

The docs document is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TRo9RG6R2ZOBqXQEJtBhRBLKzu9XOlFycamYplkma14/edit)

I have tried with

```js
function doGet(e) {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TRo9RG6R2ZOBqXQEJtBhRBLKzu9XOlFycamYplkma14/edit');
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var paras = body.getParagraphs();
    for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
        if (paras[i].editAsText().getText().indexOf("##") == 0) {
            //var listItem = body.insertListItem(childIndex, listItem)
            var text = paras[i].editAsText().getText()
            var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(paras[i])
            var element = body.removeChild(paras[i])
            element.appendListItem(text).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
        }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success" + body.getChildIndex(paras[3]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. But i would be looking at the `Body.insertListItem()` method and not the `Body.appendListItem()` one.

You could for example change your for-loop to the following:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
  if (paras[i].editAsText().getText().indexOf("##") == 0) {
    // This element is a future list item
    var elem = paras[i];
    // What's the text going to be?
    var text = elem.editAsText().getText()
    // Where will it be inserted?
    var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(elem)
    // I should remove the old element
    body.removeChild(elem)
    // And take it's place with this new one with Glyph.
    body.insertListItem(childIndex, text).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
  }
}
```

---

#### References:

- [Body.insertListItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertlistitemchildindex,-text)